# Why does my Node.js script not see any UDP packets that are being sent on a specific port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, networking, udp

I have the C# app that sends the UDP packets for the specific IP and port and it works well, because I have the other app that receives those packages. Now I would like to send them so that I can display it on my webpage - I've read that the node.js will fit perfectly here.

I installed the current version of node.js under windows environment and took the following code:

```
var PORT            = 19777;
var MULTICAST_GROUP = "224.0.0.251";

var dgram = require("dgram");

var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

client.on("message", function(message, rinfo) {
    console.log("received: ",message,rinfo);
});
client.on("listening", function() {
    console.log("listening on ",client.address());

    client.setBroadcast(true);
    client.setTTL(64);
    client.setMulticastTTL(64);
    client.setMulticastLoopback(true);
    client.addMembership(MULTICAST_GROUP);
    client.send(payload, 0, payload.length, PORT, MULTICAST_GROUP, function(err,bytes) {
        console.log("err: "+err+" bytes: "+bytes);
        // client.close();
    });
});
client.on("close", function() {
    console.log("closed");
});
client.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("error: ",err);
});
client.bind(19777);
```

And now I started sending packets on the following ip `"224.0.0.251"` and port `19777` from my C# app - however, after runnint the client app I've got the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>node client.js
error:  { [Error: bind EADDRINUSE] code: 'EADDRINUSE', errno: 'EADDRINUSE', sysc
all: 'bind' }
```

What am I doing wrong? And - after fixing this issue - will I be able to just see all packets in the console? Thanks.

------------- EDIT:

Following the advice of John, I modified the app so that only node.js is listening now on that port. Thanks to this I made a progress and on the output of my console I get:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>node client.js
listening on  { address: '0.0.0.0', family: 'IPv4', port: 19777 }
C:\Users\user\Desktop\client.js:19
    client.send(payload, 0, payload.length, PORT, MULTICAST_GROUP, function(er
                ^
ReferenceError: payload is not defined
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\godyckim\Desktop\client.js:19:17)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at startListening (dgram.js:139:10)
    at dgram.js:230:7
    at dns.js:85:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

but still no packets are visible.. Ok, I see that I didn't define the payload variable... What I want to achieve is to receive the packets that are sent by udp and either display it in the node.js console (that would be a start for me), or transfer it further so that I can see them in the browser. In the second case - what exactly I'm doing wrong now? Thanks!

Comment: this usually means you're trying to bind two apps (your node.js and c# app in this case) to the same ip/port.. keep in mind that only the receiving side has to listen on a specific port to get packets sent to it.. it doesn't matter from which port they're coming.

Comment: Thanks @John, I added an edit section to my post above, can you take a look at it?

Comment: well you're trying to send a payload (which should be a buffer) but there is none.. you could create one using `var payload = new Buffer('A wild message appears');`

Comment: thanks @John, that did the trick and now I can see lots of packets in my console output. I'm super happy and glad you gave me that hint :). Now I would like to work with that data, but I don't know where exactly they are stored in my case. Are they stored in some kind of table? Or list?

Comment: in memory.. you could easily write every incoming packet to a file using `fs. writeFile` -> https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs but this is actually outside of this questions' scope